# Get text between two patterns with egrep and awk

Tags: regex, bash, awk, grep

I'm trying to parse a command's help file to grab all the arguments the command excepts.

Here is some text from the help file:

```
* --digest:
  Set the digest for fingerprinting (defaults to the digest used when
  signing the cert). Valid values depends on your openssl and openssl ruby
  extension version.

* --debug:
  Enable full debugging.

* --help:
  Print this help message

* --verbose:
  Enable verbosity.

* --version:
  Print the puppet version number
```

I want to just grab `--argument` and nothing else.

I almost got it with this command, but its still including the ":" which I want to exclude:

```
puppet cert --help | egrep '^* --(.*):$' | awk '{print $2}'
--all:
--allow-dns-alt-names:
--digest:
--debug:
--help:
--verbose:
--version:
```

Why is `'^* --(.*):$'` including the ":" shouldn't it be matching everything between `'^* --'` and `':$'` ?

Comment: `sed -nr 's/^\* |:.*//p'`

Comment: Once upon a time we had a perfectly good tool for `find`ing files and it was named `find` and then the GNU guys screwed around with `grep` to add file-finding args. Once upon a time we had a perfectly good tool for `ed`iting `s`treams (including selecting strings matching a regexp) and it was named `sed` and then the GNU guys screwed around with `grep` to add stream-editing args. I can't wait for them to add the ability to `sort` the output, etc. - soon we won't need any other commands, just the almighty `grep`. Wish the GNU guys who changed `grep` had read a UNIX book before screwing with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> shouldn't it be matching everything between `^* --` and `:$` ?

Actually, no. You're capturing a group, but it won't print just the group. I suggest using the `-P` flag to use Perl regex, and look arounds. In your case, this might be enough:

```
$ cert --help | grep -Po '^\* \K--\w+'
```

Note that I also used the `-o` option, to print only the matched content, not the whole line. This eliminates the usage of *awk*.

---

A more complete line based on your initial thoughts and more look arounds:

```
$ cert --help | grep -Po '^\* \K--.*(?=:)'
```

---

Edit: as noted in the comments and fine answer by *mklement0*, this requires GNU grep. You can however do the same with Perl itself, which certainly is probably already installed in your system.

```
$ cert --help | perl -nle 'print $1 if /^\* (--\w+)/'
```

This works like a line of code inside a loop. Which is automatically generated by the `-nle`. `-n` for the input look, `-l` for the auto line break, and `-e` to present the line of code.

The line of Perl code prints the first captured group if the line matches the regex. So it combines ideas from your original solution too.

For a complete POSIX compliant answer, check the [answer by mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34099542/557306) here in this page.

Comment: Well done, but please note that using `-P` requires _GNU_ `grep`.

Comment: @mklement0 true, I will add a note and maybe a Perl version itself. Thanks!

Comment: Weird neither of those work for me. It says "grep: nothing to repeat". But I just found this works grep -o ' --\w*\b'. Whats the difference between -Po and just -o? I running grep (GNU grep) 2.20

Comment: @red888 might not be available in your system. Just a moment, I will edit with a safer Perl version. `-P` is for perl regex, needed for the lookarounds. `-o` is to print the matched content only, as I said in the answer

Comment: @red888: The 'nothing to repeat' probably stems from not escaping the meant-to-be-a-literal `*` in `^*` - try `^\*`.

Comment: @mklement0 Yes that's the problem. Sorry, I didn't notice it well. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @red888 I updated the answer with a Perl version too.

Answer (score 3):

To provide **a POSIX-compliant alternative** to [sidyll's elegant *GNU* `grep` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34099550/45375) (which also explains why the OP's approach didn't work):

---

**Update**:  Avinash Raj points out in a comment that `sed` is an option, which indeed allows for a POSIX-compliant single-tool solution: `sed` allows us to match entire lines of interest and replace them with the contents of a capture group (the part of the line of interest):

```
puppet cert --help | sed -n 's/^\* \(--.*\):$/\1/p'
```

<sup>Note that since `sed` is used without the - nonstandard - `-r` / `-E` option, a *basic* regular expression must be used, where `(` and `)` must be `\`-escaped to act as capture-group delimiters.</sup>

---

Original answer:

```
puppet cert --help | egrep '^\* --.+:$' | awk -F '\\* |:' '{print $2}'
```

Note:

- `^*` was replaced with `^\*` so as to ensure that `*` is matched as a *literal*, and `(.*)` was replaced with `.+`, because (a) there is nothing to be gained by a capture group here, and (b) it's fair to assume that at least *one* letter follows the `--`.
- `-F '\\* |:'` uses either literal `*<space>` or `:` as the field separator, which ensures that only the `--...` token (the second field) is printed.

Comment: you may use sed also.

Comment: Thanks for the references. I now added a Perl version. Thinking in POSIX compliance, it would fit now since Perl is required :-D thanks for your great explanations in this original tools solution too. Already upvoted

Comment: @sidyll: My pleasure; nice job on the Perl solution too. (I'm not sure what you're saying with respect to Perl and POSIX, but in case you're thinking that Perl is part of POSIX: I don't think it is; however, Perl _is_ available on the major non-GNU-utilities platform OS X).

Comment: Doubtful, true. I believe to have read it here somewhere in this site about that, but I can't find. You're right and I don't think it is included indeed. Although being mostly available like you said.